# WebApp 'randomly' caching some pages and not others

Tags: ios, caching, web-applications

I'm trying to create a webapp and I'm hitting a maddening problem on iOS 5.  I have a web-app that starts off with a linear four page "tour".  (e.g. tour1 goes to tour2, tour2 goes to tour3, etc)

When I save the site as a webapp (not using a manifest), it will cache tour steps 1, 3 and 4, but not step 2 and the registration page after step 4.  It makes no sense!

I've tried adding an .htaccess to the index directory and the directory containing the tourX.html files, per the suggestion on [Mobile Web App not clearing cache properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337631/mobile-web-app-not-clearing-cache-properly).

I've also cleared Safari cache, deleted the web app, and force closed the browser.  I still get the same results - for some reason it is fine pulling the latest copy of tour2.html and register.html, but refuses to pull the latest version of other pages.  It feels random, but of course nothing is really random in the computer world.

Has anyone experienced anything like this with web apps?

Comment: Is there anything significantly different between the pages that are being cached and the ones that aren't?

Comment: Have u tried a restore? It may be a configuration error.

Comment: @icktoofay: No, that's the ironic part.  The pages are basically a copy/paste of each other, with plain text changes.  (They are separate pages to take advantage of JQuery Mobile page transitions)