# Difference iOS Safari and webapp CSS behaviour

Tags: ios, css, web-applications, safari

I use `text-overflow: ellipsis` in a webpage.
It does function as expected in Safari on iPad, but not in the webapp (link on home screen) viewed on the same device.
Is this a shortcoming of the iOS webapp implementation or am I overlooking something?
ANSWER: what happens is the iPad webapp cache does not react to clearing the Safari cache. So when I edit the webpage I don't see the change in the webapp.
You need to [add a manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16354558/1834033).

Answer (score 0):

Text-overflow is pretty well supported, so I'm guessing something is going wrong here.

Do you also have `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden;` set on the element as well? They're both needed to get the ellipsis to happen, as well as the container actually being small enough to trigger overflow.

Comment: I checked some more and it seems it is a problem with caching.When I change something in the website, clear the iPad Safari cache and start Safari again, I see the change. Then I put the link on the home screen, close Safari and start the webapp, I do not see the change! Now I know where to start searching. Thanks for your input.